# DataBinding to GridView

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, gridview

I Have a gridview object and I want to bind it to an Object.

My Object is

```
public class BindingObject
{
    public ColorInfo Color { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public struct ColorInfo 
    {
        public string Red { get; set; }
        public string Green { get; set; }
        public string Blue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want that in the gridview I will see only the properties `Name` and `Red`
Now when I bound it my gridview see like this: `Color` and `Name`, but I want  `Red` and `Name`.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

**Update**: Thanks, but if I want to add a property setter

```
public string Red { 
    get { return this.Color.Red; } 
    set { this.Color.Red = value; } 
}
```

I get this error:

> Error 1 Cannot modify the return value of 'DataBinding.BindingObject.Color' 
>   because it is not a variable

Thank you for the fast reply

Comment: ASP .NET or WinForms GridView ? Makes quite a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Change ColorInfo from struct to class or use fields in this struct instead of properties.

```
    public struct ColorInfo 
    {
        public string Red;
        public string Green;
        public string Blue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Red,Green,Blue all are key words, please avoid to use key words